# Kotlin: Prevent mixup of same typed parameters

Tags: kotlin

How can I save the cats from being served for dinner?

```
data class Animal(
    val name: String
)

data class ToDo(
    val toEat: List<Animal>,
    val toFeed: List<Animal>,
)

val cats = listOf(Animal("fluffy"))
val chickens = listOf(Animal("chic"))

// help the kittens!!!
ToDo(cats, chickens)
```

Note: This is a simplified example and I cant change the Type of `cats`/`chickens` to something like `Cat`/`Chicken.`

Comment: what's wrong with just swapping the arguments?

Comment: I would like to prevent it from happening in the future by future-me/other devs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't give them different types, then I don't think there's any way the compiler could spot this problem.  However, you could make it more obvious by simply giving the parameter names:

```
ToDo(toEat = chickens, toFeed = cats)
```

That way, it's very clear which list goes with which parameter.  (It also means that the order of the parameters doesn't matter; you can swap them, as long as each is given once.)

It would still compile if you mixed them up:

```
ToDo(toEat = cats, toFeed = chickens)
```

…but at least that would be obvious and doesn't need you to check the documentation to see the problem.

A caller could still choose to omit the parameter names, though.  To prevent that, you'd have to restructure the ToDo class.  For example, you could use the builder pattern, and give something like:

```
ToDo().toEat(chickens).toFeed(cats)
```

Or you could simply remove the parameters from the constructor, requiring the caller to set properties by name, e.g.:

```
ToDo().apply{ toEat = chickens; toFeed = cats }
```

Those are a little more long-winded to call, of course, but force the caller to give the property names explicitly — again, making the problem fairly obvious to human readers (if not to the compiler).

Answer (score 4):

### OOP solution

You could do the following:

1. `Animal` should be an interface.
2. `Cat` and `Chicken` should be two different implementation of `Animal`.
3. You could define an Interface named `Eatable` which will have concrete implementations.
4. Change     `val toEat: List<Animal>` in `val toEat: List<Eatable>`
5. Cat will implement `Animal` and not `Eatable`

### Another solution

Sorry but i read just now that you cannot define 2 different classes for Cat and Chicken.
You should still define this in `Animal` (pseudocode):

```
boolean eatable = false;

fun isEatable(): boolean {
    return eatable;
}
```

So you can define `Animal.eat(Animal)` to check if the animal you are trying to eat could be eaten.